# Keep data on update using *ngFor Angular+2

Tags: angular

I have `breaking-news.component.ts` and inside it I'm reading an API that returned breaking news, and I'm push the news using:

```
this.data = this.data || [];

this.response.news.forEach(news => {
this.data.push(news);
});
```

And `breaking-news.component.html`

```
 <div *ngFor="let news of data">
        <article class="hentry post">
            <mat-card>
                <mat-card-header>
...
...
...
  <p>{{news.text}}</p>
...
...
...
              </mat-card-actions>
            </mat-card>
        </article>
    </div>
```

The news is perfectly displayed in my page using `*ngFor`, but the problem is when any updates come to the API it will not appear until I refresh the page, so the `data` array will not push the new data until the API called again by refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your code seems to run outside Angulars zone, this is the reason Android doesn't recognize it needs to run change detection.

You can explicitely run code inside Angulars zone

```
constructor(private zone:NgZone) {}

foo() {
  this.zone.run(() => {
    this.data = this.data || [];

    this.response.news.forEach(news => {
      this.data.push(news);
    });
  });
}
```

but it would probably be better to figure out (and if possible fix) why your code runs outside the zone in the first place.

Comment: Can I use NgZone with web application using Angular 4?

Comment: Your question has the tag `angular`, so I assumed the question is about an Angular 2-5 web application ;-). `NgZone` is a main component of Angular - so **yes** to your question

Comment: Thanks, I thought my problem was not using Observable. Now I have nothing to do with Observable in this case.

Comment: Not really. Observables are covered by NgZone and it recognizes when an observable emits an event and then invokes change detection, but that also only works if the code actually runs inside Angulars zone, so you're back on square 1

Comment: There is no change in my view, I tried to put it in `zone` and I put `console.log("This is zone");` but in my console I got the message just one time. Nothing changes even when the API injected with data

Comment: Then the only explanation is that the data isn't actually updated. Can you create a minimal reproduction in http://stackblitz.com?